# Write a Collection object to file Python

Tags: python, collections

I have a `Collection` object as below:

```
Counter({'Saree': 5679, '': 4860, 'Cotton': 4201, 'Printed': 3715})
```

I would like to produce a CSV file containing the keys and values, sorted in descending order of value.

```
A      B
Saree  5679
       4860
Cotton 4201
Printed 3715
```

I have tried the below code where `value` is a list as `['Saree','','Cotton','printed']`:

```
for k, v in sorted(collections.Counter(value)):
    f.write(k+delimiter+v)
```

But this hasn't worked since I was assuming the Collection object is nothing but a dictionary.

The error that I get is as below:
    ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack

at

```
for k, v in sorted(collections.Counter(value)):
```

Comment: "Hasn't worked" does not tell us what is going wrong. An exception traceback would.

Comment: The part `sorted(collections.Counter(value))` looks suspicious. What is `value` there? What is the name of the variable pointing to the collection you have?

Comment: To write it to file, you can just use [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) or [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) or whatever. Then, when you read it back in, just convert the plain dictionary to a Counter. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Why don't you just `pickle` it?

Comment: sorry for the incomplete details, I will edit the question

Comment: Or are you asking how to write them to file in sorted order? In this case, try `your_counter.most_common()`

Comment: This is turning more into an XY problem. I wanted to know if there is a builtin method that could convert the Collection object into a dictionary so that I could write it in the file.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I have edited to explicitly include the CSV requirement. Now you tell us you want a dict, but the issue there is that dicts have no explicit key ordering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you appear to want to see the highest count first, the Counter's `most_common()` method gives you a list of `(key, value)` pairs with the items ordered by value. You can then iterate over that list, printing out the keys and values, as below.

```
for k, v in c.most_common():
    print "{:10} {:4}".format(k, v)
```

giving

```
Saree      5679
           4860
Cotton     4201
Printed    3715
```

OK, you want a CSV file (we are supposed somehow to intuit). This will do the job:

```
with open("file.csv", "wb") as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerows(c.most_common())
```

I am sure you will be able to cope with adding column headings.